# two married couples seating in a row

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve this problem and wanted to make sure if I am thinking right. Two married couples are seated in a row consisting 4 seats. If they take their seats in a completely random order, what is the probability that atleast one of the wives ends up sitting next to her husband.

Ci denote the event that couple i seats together. Then here we are looking for P(C1 or C2)=P(C1) +P(C2) - P(C1 and C2).

P(Ci) = (2*3!) /4! (For denominator 4! ways to arrange 4 people. For numerator , 1 couple is 1 entity then rest of the 2 along with 1 couple can sit in 3! ways and there are 2 ways HW or WH can sit).

P(C1 and C2) = (2*2!*2!) /4! (two couples can be arranged in 2! ways and each of two couples can sit HW or WH).

P(C1 or C2)= 1/2 +1/2 -1/3 = 1-1/3=2/3

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach is to note that the only way you can fail to have a couple together is if one couple is in seats $1,3$ and the other is in seats $2,4$.  So have the first person sit down somewhere.  To fail, that person's spouse must sit in the corresponding seat-probability $\frac 13$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, but perhaps you find the following approach simpler:

Let's count the arrangements that make both couples to seat separate:

- For the first seat, you can take anyone: 4 possibilities.
- For the second seat, you can take any member from the other couple: 2
  posibilities.
- For the third seat, you can only take the partner of the    person
  that is on the first seat.
- For the fourth seat, there is clearly    only one possibility.

That makes $4\times2=8$ possibilities. Hence, there are $16$ arrangements with the members of at least a couple sitting together. The probability of this is $16/24=2/3$, as you found in another way.